# Error : Extension host terminated unexpectedly in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-code

Many of you faced the error while coding in vs code unexpectedly. I had also faced the issue while coding and it seems to be a tall-order task to fix the issue.

[image]

Many of you tried even I also tried the following methods

1. removed git folder
2. uninstalled all extensions
3. disabled the git in the settings.json file
4. removed cached files of the software
5. even uninstalled VS code and installed it again, but it gives me the same error that says:
   "Extension host terminated unexpectedly"

**so what's the solution for this problem ?**

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The solution for the problem :

1. Open your vscode and launch the command palette by `ctrl` + `shift` + `p`
   [image]
2. Start the Extension Bisect
3. You can see a pop-up window like this

[image]

If your vscode works perfectly, select "Good now"
However, if you see the error "Extension host terminated unexpectedly", select the "This is bad" option.

4. This program is a binary search algorithm which finds the extensions that cause the root problem and fix the issue that currently faces

Comment: This worked for me. First it disabled 36 extensions, then I said Good Now, then it did 18 and so on. Finally, I cancelled it when the extension I was interested in was enabled. Did not get to the root of it though.

Comment: I don't know why this is not referenced more. When extension breaks you might not know if that is the actual extension you want to use or another one. (In my case LiveShare was the culprit)